# Is there any difference between black transparent and white transparent?

Tags: android, colors

If I want to make a gradient from black `#F000`to transparent `#0000`, is there a difference between using transparent black (`#0000`) and transparent white (`#0FFF`)? It doesn't matter?

I am not talking about final result, which will be the same, but performance or best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, there is an important difference. Because not only the alpha will change gradually in the gradient transition but also the RGB components. While from `#F000` to `#0000` the RGB components are the same and you will always see black colors going transparent, in the other case, from `#F000` to `#0FFF` the RGB components will change gadually and you will see some colors half-white on the gradient.

Using this example of gradient on xml:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#F000"
    android:endColor="#0000"
    android:type="linear"/>
```

You will see the diference in the preview between using black transparent (`#0000`) and white transparent (`#0FFF`).

You can read [an article explaining this topic](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-dev-tip-3-99da754151ad#.820rog65t) here.